# How to add maven dependency in Pom.xml for Firefox and Internet Explore?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, automation, pom.xml

How to add maven dependency in Pom.xml for Firefox and Internet Explore?

Please find the below POM.XML dependency

org.seleniumhq.selenium
            selenium-server
            3.141.59

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Why not using chrome driver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using separate drivers for each browser use the **WebDriverManager** dependency which has most of the browser support.

[WebDriverManager maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)